# Parsing JSON with java : dynamic keys

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I need to create a JSON response with some dynamic fields in java. Here is an example of the JSON response I want to return :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "completed_at": 1400515821,
    "<uuid>": {
        type: "my_type",
        ...
    }, 
    "<uuid>": {
        type: "my_type",
        ...
    }
}
```

The "success" and the "completed_at" fields are easy to format. How can I format the  fields? What would be the corresponding java object?

Basically I want to work with 2 java objects :

```
public class ApiResponseDTO {

    private boolean success;
    private DateTime completedAt;

    ...
}
```

and

```
public class AuthenticateResponseDTO extends ApiResponseDTO {

    public List<ApplianceResponseDTO> uuids = new     ArrayList<ApplianceResponseDTO>();

}
```

These java objects don't correspond to the expected JSON format. It would work if I could change the JSON format to have a list, but I can't change it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will the JSON value mapped to `<uuid>` always be the same?

Comment: And will the dynamic keys always be named `<uuid>`? JSON has undefined behavior for duplicate keys.

Comment: If you could wrap this similair parts into separate object you could store it as Map: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548380/gson-fromjson-to-java-class-structure-where-property-names-are-not-known

Comment: Instead of <uuid>, I will have values like "ae12-54ef-dfd...", so I won't have duplicate keys. The inner json will always be the same (type, updated date ...).
I've seen this answer @Pshemo, but in this example the map is named "details". In my case, I won't have a named map.
The solution might be really easy but I can't see it...

Comment: Are you able to change structure of this JSON? If so just wrap your set of `"completed_at":1400515821, "uuid1":{data1}, "uuid2":{data2}` into something like `"completed_at":1400515821, "details":{"uuid1":{data1},"uuid2":{data2}}` and now you can use Map without problems.

Comment: It would be much easier but unfortunately I can't...

Answer (score 0):

You can massage your data into JSON form using the javax.json library, specifically the [JsonObjectBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html) and the [JsonArrayBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html).  You'll probably want to nest a few levels of a toJson() method which will either give you the string representation you're looking for, or the JsonObject/JsonArray you desire.  Something like this:

```
JsonArray value = null;
JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (ApplianceResponseDTO apr : uuids) {
    builder.add(apr.toJson());
}
value = builder.build();
return value;
```